# Steps & Calorie data returned from Cloud API does not match with what shows up in MS Health

Tags: microsoft-band

I am just pulling some data from Cloud API and the results that I am getting back, do not match with what is logged in Microsoft Health app.

Out of 4 data points for 2 days, only 1 is a match:

Calories - Cloud API Day 1: 2,691
 
Calories - MS Health Day 1: 2,693
Calories - Cloud API Day 2: 3,468
Calories - MS Health Day 2: 3,490

Steps - Cloud API Day 1: 9,052
Steps - MS Health Day 1: 9,052
Steps - Cloud API Day 2: 22,786
Steps - MS Health Day 2: 22,936

I pulled the data hourly and add it up to a full day.
https://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Summaries/hourly?startTime=2015-12-10T08:00:00.000Z&endTime=2015-12-12T08:00:00.000Z

I tried pulling the data daily, however the numbers are even more off.

Anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

---

It looks like the data reported in Microsoft Health App and what is actually logged by the Band do not match.

[MSHealthApp / Band Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFJ4H.jpg)

In the photo above, I just synced my band with Microsoft Health and for some reason the Microsoft Health App is over reporting the number of steps that I have taken, 13,078 steps on the MS Band and 13,230 reported in the Microsoft Health App. 
I believe that this is why I am not getting matching numbers.

Looks like there is some kind of fundamental bug in the Microsoft Health App.

I will use the number returned by the Cloud Api and ignore any information in the Microsoft Health App.

Comment: What time zone (+/- UTC) is your phone set to?  If you want to see matching numbers you need to ensure that time periods for each day requested in the Cloud API match what the phone considers a "day", given its timezone.

Comment: The daily sum is based on hourly pull ("hourly?" param above) and I aligned them based on my time zone. I did go back more days and out of 7 days, I got 5 to match exactly and 2 do not match. Maybe this is just odd log bug that happened for the couple of days that I am looking at.
Similar thing happened once when my band ran out of battery because when I started it later it said that I spend over 15000 calories for that day, which is not possible. Additional to that, this high outlier number seems like it was not included in my averages because my weekly calories spend was still within range

Comment: In your example URL, you're asking for hourly summaries for two total days, starting at 8AM (GMT).  Is your phone also set to GMT?  Which hourly segments are you using to add to a full day?

Comment: Phil, the numbers do not match between what is reported in the Microsoft Health App and what I got back from the Cloud API. They are very slightly off, like in the example above for Day 1, I get the steps to match however the calories are off by 2 calories. I just added some additional information to this, I noticed that in general the numbers between Microsoft Health App and my Band do not match, in the photo above, after just syncing the Band with the Health App, the Health App is reporting 13,230 whereas the Band says 13,078. I find it odd for those number to not match right after synching.

Comment: You are not providing enough information to help explain the discrepancies you are seeing.  The time zone to which the phone is set is key to understanding the Cloud API queries needed to "match" the Health application.  What time zone is the phone set to?  Which hourly segments (in your example above, which is a 48-hour span but not aligned to a typical "day") are you using to sum to the 24-hour day that you're comparing to the application?  The step count between the Band and the Health application can vary when it's including steps taken when carrying the phone but not wearing the Band.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental issue with how the steps are tracked on the band and how they are synced with cloud api. Here is a scenario and maybe I am just having a defective band:
1.I walk and I have displayed on my MS Band display a 10,123 steps and I stop moving
2.I sync between my MS Health app and the Band
3.My MS Health App display different amount of step from what is shown on my Band display
The image that I uploaded above shows that and I believe that is why I am not seeing matching result between what is shown on my Band display and what I am pulling with Cloud API